# Shopify.AppMessenger failed to parse JSON !_{h:'app-iframe'} from origin

Tags: google-api, shopify

[image]Getting an error from shopify app messenger
Shopify.AppMessenger failed to parse JSON !_{h:'app-iframe'} from origin

```
gapi.load('client:auth2', function() {
    gapi.client.init({
    apiKey: 'AIzaSccxxxxxxxxxxxTflBRAM',
        clientId: '33418xxxxxxx8-g8u6c3e93qbfvna5r46n7sxxxxxxp7n2e9.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'
    }).then(
        // On success
        function(success) {
            // After library is successfully loaded then enable the login button

        }, 
        // On error
        function(error) {
            //alert('Error : Failed to Load Library');
        }
    );
});
```